# What is the most effecient way to group this Redshift table?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

```
+----------+-----------+----------+
| user_id  | order_id  | cal_date |
+----------+-----------+----------+
| 10000060 | 304452419 | 9/8/16   |
| 10000060 | 304452419 | 9/8/16   |
| 10000060 | 305742547 | 9/8/16   |
| 10000060 | 306345571 | 9/3/16   |
| 10000214 | 300179313 | 8/21/16  |
| 10000214 | 321227135 | 1/18/17  |
| 10000214 | 321227135 | 1/18/17  |
| 10000214 | 321227135 | 1/18/17  |
| 10000322 | 281254713 | 2/7/16   |
| 10000322 | 281254713 | 2/7/16   |
| 10000322 | 281254713 | 2/7/16   |
| 10000322 | 307282405 | 9/19/16  |
| 10000322 | 307282405 | 9/19/16  |
| 10000322 | 307282405 | 9/19/16  |
| 10000322 | 307282405 | 9/19/16  |
| 10001708 | 273598247 | 8/18/16  |
| 10001708 | 293004133 | 8/18/16  |
| 10001708 | 293004133 | 8/18/16  |
| 10001708 | 293004133 | 8/18/16  |
|   100018 | 304414889 | 9/4/16   |
|  1000193 | 322124963 | 1/23/17  |
| 10001964 | 292928587 | 5/18/16  |
| 10001964 | 293084327 | 5/20/16  |
+----------+-----------+----------+
```

my goal is to output a table that has UNIQUE user_ids, the latest cal_date for that user_id, and the highest order_id.

the part that is throwing me off is that there can be different order_ids on the same cal_date for a user_id (look at user_id 10000060).

i've done this in an inefficient way (where I used a couple subqueries and ranking function). seems like there would be a better way to do it? any thoughts?

Comment: Sounds like two simple MAX, but I assume you want the highest order id with the latest cal_date? Then it's based on ROW_NUMBER...

Comment: hi - yes i would like to take the highest order_id with the latest cal_date

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select b.user_id, max(b.orderid) maxorderid, b.cal_date from(
select user_id, max(cal_date)cal_date
from yourtable a
group by user_id)a
join  yourtable b on a.userid=b.user_id and a.cal_date=b.cal_date
group by b.user_id, b.cal_date
```

Comment: if i follow correctly - the problem with this is that the max(order_id) will not necessarily be the latest cal_date. for example, you can have order id 456 on cal_date 1/1/2016, but order id 123 on 1/2/2016. and in this case, i rather have order_id 123 since it is on a later cal date

Comment: right so in your inner query you define user_id and max(cal_date) - then u join back to the original data set and take the higher orderid- is this not what you are trying to do?

Comment: ok sorry i misread your query. i believe this works as well. thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Use Row_number and sort the data to get the row you want on top:

```
select user_id,
   order_id,
   cal_date
from
 (
    select user_id,
       order_id,
       cal_date,
       row_number() 
       over (partition by user_id
             order by cal_date desc, order_id desc) as rn
    from mytable
 ) as dt
where rn = 1
```

Comment: ok this is very similar to what i did, though i did a couple of extra unnecessary steps... i just wanted to make sure that it was an ok way to do it (seemed like a lot of work to do a simple task). ty